# How do I prevent from timedout

Tags: php, dom

I use this method to extract data from html of a website. But sometimes it gets stuck. How do I prevent it from being timedout? Like rather than giving some weird errors it should simply say; can't fetch result right now

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://homeshopping.pk/search.php?category%5B%5D=&search_query='.$homeshoppingSearch); 
$pk_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 

if(!empty($html)){ 

$pk_doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors(); 

$pk_xpath = new DOMXPath($pk_doc);
/
//Homeshopping
$pk_row = $pk_xpath->query('//a[@class=""]');
$pk_row2 = $pk_xpath->query('//a[@class="price"]');
$pk_row3 = $pk_xpath->query('(//a[@class="price"])//@href');

//HomeShopping
if($pk_row->length > 0){
    $rowarray = array();
    foreach($pk_row as $row){
        $rowarray[]= $row->nodeValue;
       // echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
if($pk_row2->length > 0){
    $row2array = array();
    foreach($pk_row2 as $row2){
        $row2array[]=$row2->nodeValue;
       // echo $row2->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
if($pk_row3->length > 0){
    $row3array = array();
    foreach($pk_row3 as $row3){
        $row3array[]=$row3->nodeValue;
        //echo $row3->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [set_time_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function. It lets you set how long the execution time may be

Another way would be to set the time limit right in the [php ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) if you got the rights to edit it